# How to use Jade/Haml with Rails 3.1 asset pipeline and backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, haml, asset-pipeline, pug, rails-3.1

Currently I am using [backbone-rails](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) in my Rails app. I would like to know how to use client side Haml/Jade backbone.js with that gem and the rails asset pipline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using [haml_coffee_assets](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets) and it works perfectly !

Haml templates are compiled with the Rails assets, and then on the client side you "render" the templates.

test.hamlc:

```
%span
   = @title
```

on client side:

```
JST["test"]({title: "Yeah"})
```

=> `<span>Yeah</span>`

**UPDATE** My project has grown very big now (Feb 2012), and I confirm it's working really, really well !